# Connected to MySQL server, but no tables are listed/shown

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I am trying to create a JPA project, and eclipse does connect to the database, but no tables are shown. The database do have tables, and the user "john" have all permits in the database. There is no problem executing queries from the prompt or using a MySQL client.

Here is the connection setup in "Driver Properties":

> Drivers: MySQL JDBC Driver
>   Database: myDatabase
>   URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
>   username: john
>   password: ******

The "Test connection" button works fine, the connection is estabilished, but in the tables folder, it is empty.

Using jre7, tomcat 7.0, Mysql 5.6.0, Eclipse Luna 4.4.2, mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know that. that is why **this is a self-answered question**. Since I found no similar question in SO, I decided to post both Q and A, portraying the situation before I began searching and the answer that worked for me. Should I refrain from doing so in the future?

Answer (score 10):

The connection String should list the schema.

Source: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=155563&goto=675194&#msg_675194

> So, if the JDBC connection string is only like:
>   jdbc:mysql://[server_name]:3306/ instead of
>   jdbc:mysql://[server_name]:3306/[schema_name]
>
> than Eclipse shows no tables neither in Database Explorer, nor in JPA
>   table generation.

Changing the connection string from
`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306`
to
`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase`

correctly displays the tables.

Comment: You sir are correct!